# Is there a quad-core configuration of the 13'' MacBook Pro 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there a quad-core configuration of the 13 in MacBook Pro 2016 model? There is a quad core option for 15 inch, but I can't find one for 13 inch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, according to Apple's website. 13" model doesn't have quad-core model(don't know why, always wanted that option), not even build to order ones. It is 15" exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of a real quad core, no.

However, it is worth noting that all possible CPU configurations do support **Turbo Boost 2.0** and **Hyper Threading**. Hyper-threading will be of more interest to you.

Here is a brief summary of both:

- **Turbo Boost 2.0** automatically increases the speed of the active cores to improve performance when needed. Depending on the actual configuration, this boost will range from a boost of 3.3GHz up to 3.6GHz). You can read more about this [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html). You can also [disable and enable Turbo Boost](http://osxdaily.com/2016/07/13/disable-enable-turbo-boost-mac/) at will.
- **Hyper Threading** allows the system to recognize four total *cores* (two real and two virtual). You can also read more about [Hyper-Threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).